# Передать массив строк в описании объекта класса

Tags: c#

Задача такая, есть класс, содержащий массив строк. Как сделать так, что бы при описании объекта класса, можно было передавать любое количество строк в конструктор. (В конструкторе строки принимаются с помощью params)

```
Class A
{
   string[] str;

   public A(params string[] str1)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < Str.Length;i++ )
                Str[i] = str1[i];
   }
}
```

На такую запись ругается, что мол массив null, как его сделать резиновым?

Comment: В обьявлениях не показано что такое Str (нет обьявления), он не равен str, это делает вопрос бесполезным даже если есть ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё, отмена, правильно будет в конструкторе записать просто

Str=str1 без никаких циклов